# Trouble shoot a spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I wrote a spark streaming job that is having a few issues in terms of performance. I looked into the UI and found that every 10th batch is taking 6 to 10 seconds.

[image]

Inside the taks that is long running, it has created 2 job ids. One that has taken most of the time and has done nothing and another job that has completed on time.

[image]

Can anyone guide me how I can trouble shoot this.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot would be great. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Please share you program, input sizes and why you think it's too big time

Comment: Thanks, on a high level, I am using 20 receivers to receive data parallely and use mapwithState to store state data. Can you please tell me where does the mapwithstate store intermittent data